# Show that u is radially symmetric.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider $\Delta u=1$ on an annulus $a<r<b$ in $\Bbb{R}^2$, with $u$ vanishing on both the inner and outer circles. Here $0<a<b$, and $r=|x|=({x_1}^2+{x_2}^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for $x=(x_1,x_2) \in \Bbb{R}^2$. Show that $u$ is radially symmetric.

I am not sure how to get to that, but I know that Laplace equation is invariant under all rigid motions. And the given jacobian matrix is $J=\begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ -r \sin \theta & r \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Rewrite the PDE in polar coordinates.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator

Step 2: assume the solution is only depending on $r$ and solve the ODE.

Step 3: Use or proof uniqueness of the poison equation. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson%27s_equation

Let me know if you need further assistance with one of the steps.